# Why should I use an expiring token on 'forgot password' pages?

Tags: security, passwords

I am building a forgot password page. I've been reading around and many sources recommend to have users enter their email address, which will then add a token in the DB and send them a link with the token attached as  GET variable.

I was curious why that token is really necessary?If the token is expired, anybody with bad intentions and access to your email, can go right back to the forgot password page and enter your email again to get a new password reset link.

I don't see the point of even having a token that expires at some point if somebody has access to your email address. Why should I use an expiring token on 'forgot password' pages?

Comment: For the case someone has already access to the email account, you would ask for another identity verification, typically the answer to a ‘security question’ that *only* the real person can answer correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Let's assume that a person with malicious intent wants access to your account on example.org, but *doesn't* have access to your email account. Also assume example.org's "forgot my password" algorithm's tokens don't expire.

This person will, if he's at least half-smart, do his research and setup a fake account on example.org and hit the "forgot my password" button and get a reset link himself to find out how these tokens are built (at least, the format they're in).

Then, said person types in *your* username and clicks the "forgot my password" button that emails *you* a reset-link that doesn't expire, but they don't care about that - they know the format that the reset-token is in; so, they can just brute force the reset-page with incrementing tokens until they find a valid hit.

This approach, of course, will technically find every reset-request that hasn't been fulfilled but will also find yours too.

If tokens expire, and within a reasonable time limit, the amount of time between the generation of said-token and it's expiration will occur far before the attacker can "guess" it. Of course, there's always the chance that you see the email prior to them guessing it too - but that's far less secure than adding an expiration time =P

Comment: I see. Thanks for the explanation. The tokens do nothing to protect someone who has a compromised email account though, is that correct?

Comment: @zeckdude Correct. Very little is secure if someone's main email account is compromised.

Comment: Would anyone even try to bruteforce 128bit token (as we all know usually people use random md5() as a token)? (though personally I also expire the reset link ;-)

Comment: @zerkms Maybe not with a direct incremental approach, but if you know the algorithm used to create the token (say, for instance, `$token = md5(time() . '|' . $username);`), the number of combinations become feasible (especially if you know the time you hit the "forgot my password" button =P)

Answer (score 0):

You can ask the question the other way round: *Why should a reset-link be valid for ever?*

When i ask for a password reset link, i will use it normally in about one hour or two. There is no advantage, when i can click the link two years later, probably i won't remember that such a reset-link even exists. And it's easy to request a new link.

On the other hand, if someone in future gains access to my e-mail account, or maybe gets a backup of my e-mails somehow, then he can use the reset-link. Being able to read the e-mails doesn't necessarily mean, that one can login to the e-mail account. There is for example the open e-mail client in the office, a forgotten logout in an internet-cafe, a lost mobile phone...

The token itself should make sure, that an attacker cannot predict the code of a new reset-link. It is better to use a random code, instead of a code that was generated by parameters like username, current time, or e-mail address.

Generally one can say, why use a weaker scheme, if there is a stronger one, when the work for coding is not significantly harder?